# Dell M3800 with 14.04 LTS HDMI randomly cuts out

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, dell, hdmi

I have a M3800 plugged into a Dell U2913WM via HDMI

I'm using the nVidia binary driver (331.113 from nvidia-331), which is the recommended driver

I've used multiple HDMI cables, and plugged into multiple monitors with the same issue, so I'd imagine it to either be a socket problem or a GFX card/driver issue

Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue? If so, how are you resolving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to download the 
[Precision M3800 Ubuntu driver package (Ubuntu 14.04)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=VW84F&fileId=3458728014&osCode=UB14A&productCode=precision-m3800-workstation&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS) from Dell.

Which includes all the necessary drivers and patches for the M3800.
You just need to download it on a 14.04 system, and follow the instructions there to get it installed.

If this issue happen again with that driver, you might need to check the hardware status to see if this is a hardware issue, or open a bug for this.